# C++20 [[no_unique_address]] not working with clang's win32-coff target

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, c++20, coff

While working with `clang-13` in C++20, I noticed that the `x86_64-pc-win32-coff` cross-compile target seems to outright reject the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute. This attribute is otherwise supported for other targets that I tested with.

Consider this minimal example:

```cpp
struct bar {};

struct foo {
    [[no_unique_address]] bar b;
};
```

which, when compiled with `-target=x86_64-pc-win32-coff`, produces

```
<source>:4:7: warning: unknown attribute 'no_unique_address' ignored [-Wunknown-attributes]
    [[no_unique_address]] bar b;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/rMjzn9EM8)</kbd>

Is it a known issue for different targets to reject attributes, or is this a product of just the underlying cross-compile target? I know that MSVC historically did not do empty-base optimization and kept this for ABI compatibility; is this a product of that compatibility?

I *suspect* this is likely a bug in the target since it does not fully satisfy the C++20 spec, but I'm unsure of whether there is a pragmatic or known reason as to why this attribute is outright rejected, when other cross-compile targets seem to work without issue.

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful, but it works in the `i686-w64-windows-gnu` target (the MinGW one).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat as far as I can tell, most other targets seem to work. It seems to just be the `win32-coff` format that fails so far. Unfortunately I need this target, as (U)EFI binaries need to be in PE/COFF format, and there is no `none-coff` target for LLVM (attempting this [triggers an ICE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/hhPchx6W9))

Comment: Huh. So I tried several different targets randomly, and `--target=x86_64-mingw32-coff` worked (as in, compiled and `static_assert` on the struct size passed - but don't know how to link and run the result).

Comment: Interesting find! Unfortunately, testing this with `clang-13` on my mac triggered an ICE -- so it seems this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`no_unique_address` is something whose primary support has to be handled at the ABI level. Both the Itanium ABI and Microsoft's de-facto ABI (aka: whatever MSVC does) support `no_unique_address`... kinda.

See, Microsoft is not at present willing to cause an ABI break. And since the attribute does nothing under a C++17 build, this would mean that compiling the same header for C++17 and C++20 could cause ODR violations.

So instead, they're holding off on fully implementing the attribute. They have the code ready to go in the compiler (and you can even use the MSVC-specific attribute `msvc::no_unique_address` to get the same effect). But until they do an ABI break, they don't intend to support it.

As such, Clang appears to be following Microsoft's lead on this.

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't realize they introduced a custom `msvc::no_unique_address` attribute to handle this. Thanks for the great answer